# Identifying important interactions between features using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, interaction

Let's say I have a set of features: a, b, c, d, e, f. I'm now interested in identifying possible interactions between these features that best predict an outcome. For example, it could be that the features a, f, and the interactions a:b:g, d:f and c:e are the 5 most important factors that predict the outcome. It is not only important for an algorithm to account for feature interactions, but I also want to be able to identify these interactions.

How could I approach this problem with machine learning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for [association rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning). One example algorithm for recovering these is [Apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm).

If you want a textbook that covers them, [Mining Massive Datasets](http://www.mmds.org/) is one choice (Frequent Itemsets chapter - it contains lots of exercises).